# puppet agent failing to run automatically

Tags: debian, puppet

I have two nodes besides the puppet master listed in my puppet master. The two are currently listed as unresponsive. It appears the puppet agents are failing to run automatically.

In my logs on the agents it lists:

Pastie link as its a bit long: http://pastie.org/private/uaagvz7tfqtuzboyuppztw

However if I run puppet agent -t manually:

```
   root@ex:/var/log# puppet agent -t
   Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
   Info: Retrieving plugin
   Info: Loading facts
   Info: Caching catalog for sea2.impactvps.net
   Info: Applying configuration version '1430058342'
   Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.00 seconds
```

It runs without issue and then appears responsive in the master. Until it fails to run automatically on its next run.

OS is Debian 7

Would appreciate any help that could be provided.

Comment: How are you doing the automatic runs? Using the puppet agent deamon? Cron? Mcollective? Are you sure you didn't install both open source and PE puppet?

Comment: it's like the puppet automatic is one version and puppet agent  is another. See if there are more than one puppet folder on your system.

Comment: Can you run the below and see whether it finds multiple config files.       find / -iname 'puppet.conf'

Comment: puppet was installed directly off of my puppet master: curl -k https://puppet.example.net:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash only one config file

Comment: My runs should be by the daemon as it is using defaults.

Comment: `Apr 26 09:49:59 sea2 puppet-agent[176093]: Could not send report: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey:: key values mismatch` <-- can you access the SSL cert + key in daemon mode?

Comment: What arguments is the puppet daemon running with? What do you see with `ps -eaf | grep puppet`?

Comment: @PaulHaldane root        5385       1  0 Apr22 ?        00:00:08 /opt/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppet/bin/puppet agent agent
root      700558       1  0 06:25 ?        00:00:08 /opt/puppet/bin/ruby /opt/puppet/sbin/mcollectived --pid /var/run/pe-mcollective.pid

Comment: @PetterH How would I check that

Comment: This is confusing. Are you using Puppet Enterprise?

Comment: @faker yes. The 10 node free version

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue with some of my Enterprise nodes right now, too.

Comment: @ewwhite I was able to solve mine using the solution I posted as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by clearing the certs of all of the nodes out of the master,as well as the master cert and fulling deleting the SSL directory off the agent. I had cleared the agents before but it seemed clearing the master one was required as well.